# Getting the label equal to one if the digits and label are equal

Tags: python

I am doing a machine learning project on MNIST dataset. Here is what i want to do:

I want to write a function that inputs two digits. If the prediction is right(i.e. digit is 5 and actual label says it's 5), the new label would replace '1' instead of the actual label. if the predication is wrong(i.e. digit is 5 and actual label says it's something except for 5), the new label would replace '-1' instead of the actual label.

For example,

if the digit is 2(image), the actual label is 
[2,3,5,6,...,2,3], 
then the new label would be 
[1,-1,-1,-1,...,1,-1]

here is where I am stuck

```
def binary_class(digit1, digit2,train_images,train_label):

    trained_model=train(train_images,train_label)

    for i in range (train_images.shape[0]):

        if train_images[i] ==
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is a number of mistakes in your code and in your text - please fix that; the answer you are looking for is 'list comprehension', by the way. Is there a particular reason for wanting `1` vs `-1`? Because if not, using booleans would make more sense. Either way, a straight up list comprehension will do the work.

Comment: To add to @Grismar. For MNIST unless you use a tanh as activation on the last layer or something which bounds your output to the range [-1,1] you should use [0,1]. Common final layer activations like sigmoid are in this range, so you will never get negative values.

Answer (score 0):

```
trained_model=train(train_images,train_label)

for i in range (train_images.shape[0]):

    if train_label[i] == trained_model.predict(train_images[i])[0]:
        train_label[i] = '1'
    else:
        train_label[i] = '-1'
```

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please clarify what do you want. Why do you have 2 digits in your function? Why in your example you use only one digit? Sometimes you need to write just a small function which does just one thing.

```
def get_reference(digit, train_labels):
    return [1 if label == digit else -1 for label in train_labels]
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it is both elegant and uses list comprehension which speeds up your code. Only suggestion I would make is still with the function/variable names the OP used.